# R mlogit on my data giving error 'system is computationally singular?

Tags: r, mlogit

Could anyone explains what is the error and how could I resolve it?

```
> C.m<-mlogit(choice~TotalAmount,data=C)

Error in solve.default(H, g[!fixed]) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 6.87101e-23
```

Comment: Added better title and tagged [tag:mlogit]. Also, tell us your package versions, upgrade to the latest, open a clean R session, reverify you still see your issue. Mine are mlogit 0.2.4 (maxLik 1.2.0).

Comment: And it goes without saying: **give us a reproducible code snippet, use `dput` (don't dump everything!) and `str(C.m)`** so we understand what type each of the columns of *`C.m`* are - your question currently says nothing at all about that.

Answer (score 3):

Something in your data is `computationally singular` e.g. some of the columns you are trying to do the regression on are correlated.
Maybe you can remove some of the correlated columns and try again without them.

Comment: I have filtered the variables with correlation > 0.91, but the error message remain.